# How to redefine xhtml body element with xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

This was my first question, which was answered already: [XML Schema - Is it possible to allow a certain element only once in the whole document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661652/)

Now I want to redefine `body` element of xhtml and add a unique constraint to it. This is the definition inside `xhtml-struct-1.xsd`

```
 <xs:group
        name="xhtml.html.content">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element
                name="head"
                type="xhtml.head.type"/>
            <xs:element
                name="body"
                type="xhtml.body.type"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
```

in my `redefine.xsd` I tried this:

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd">
  <xs:group name="xhtml.html.content">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="head" type="xhtml.head.type" />
      <xs:element name="body" type="xhtml.body.type" >
                <xs:unique name="highlander">
                     <xs:selector xpath=".//mylang:content"/>
                     <xs:field xpath="."/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:redefine>
```

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file:xhtml-struct-1.xsd;
>   lineNumber: 113; columnNumber: 35; mg-props-correct.2: Circular
>   definitions detected for group ':xhtml.html.content_fn3dktizrknc9pi'.
>   Recursively following the {term} values of the particles leads to a
>   particle whose {term} is the group itself.

I treid dozens of other variants but I always get strange errors which i don't understand. How can I redefine a xhtml body element with XML Schema?

Answer (score 0):

Redefining groups is working differently.

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd">
  <xs:group name="xhtml.html.content">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="xhtml.html.content">
      ... additional elements/group to be in this sequence defined here ...
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
</xs:redefine>
```

It looks like you want to redefine type "xhtml.body.type" and you should try to do that instead of redefining group "xhtml.html.content".

Maybe these snippets help:

http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter18.html

Comment: Sorry, but your answer didn't helped me. Redefining xhtml.body.type doesn't work as xs:unique is only allowed as a child of xs:element, so i can't add a unique definition to xhtml.body.type. And when i reference the group again i just 'add' further elements but i want to replace the element definition of body in this group

Comment: You're right, missed that detail. Sorry. Since I'm facing similar trouble on redefining XHTML XSD currently, I'm interested in that problem, too. I think it's related to XSD either supporting redefining superset or subset, but no replacement consisting of same elements as before. Have you ever tried doing two-step redefinition - redefine subset first containing head element in a XSD to be redefined in a second XSD into superset reintegrating body element with all your modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different parsers/validators?

Regarding my somewhat similar issue as posted on [W3C's XMLSchema Dev Mailing List](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2011Oct/0002.html) there was a private response (thus not available in archive linked before) telling me about responder's tests running different parsers with different results: libxml v20708 and MSXML v20090415 successfully validated while Xerces-J 2.11 and Saxon 9.2 both had issues with the XSD.